# Bash : Press Enter key using bash, separate lines

Tags: regex, bash, shell

For example, in file a.txt I have

```
  Apple, Orange
```

My desired output in b.txt

```
  Apple
  Orange
```

How do I separate lines in text?
I tried this but not working. It just inserts the character n

```
   sed 's/, /\n/g' a.txt > b.txt
```

Comment: Must be syntax, there is nothing wrong with your regex: http://regex101.com/r/bM3tW1

Comment: What version of `sed` are you using (i.e. what is the output of `sed --version`)?  Some versions of `sed` don't support newline escapes like `\n`.

Comment: sed --version not working .....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a one-line solution that doesn't involve sed newline behavior, you can use `tr`:

```
echo "Apple, Orange" | tr -s ', ' '\n'
```

For your files:

```
<a.txt tr -s ', ' '\n' > b.txt
```

h/t @WilliamPursell

Comment: how do I pass a whole text file to echo?

Comment: @KeenanERNLDKNF to pass a file, use `cat` (like in the second example).

Comment: Better yet: `tr -s ', ' '\n' < a.txt` ... and do *not* use `cat` for this!

Comment: @WilliamPursell i personally like writing the input redirect at the front, like `<a.txt tr -s ', ' '\n' >b.txt`

Comment: +1. I wasn't aware of the second syntax: `<a.txt tr -s ', ' '\n' > b.txt`

Comment: @slayedbylucifer it uses input and output file redirection (read the bash manpage)

Answer (score 1):

Use the enter in your `sed` line. It will be treated as a newline. Example:

```
ani ~]$ echo "Apple, Orange" | sed 's/, /\
/g'
Apple
Orange
ani ~]$
```

note the backslash

Comment: what if I have many of those? I want to convert them all with one line.... Thanks

Comment: I am sorry, I don't understand. Many of what? commas?